# Why is minnaker taking too long to load, I have installed it in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, spinnaker

I have installed minnaker in aws ec2 i have checked all pods are running, I am using the correct public DNS, my internet is stable but still taking too long to load the minnaker UI, like an hour now and it is still not loading any assist on this please.

Comment: any logs/initial investigation  please? or  show the way you installed everything? At least any info that could help community help you

Comment: Managed to sort it out @VKR, it was an issue with port forwarding after I changed my baseURL, I managed it by doing hal apply deploy, then hal apply connect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Instance has at least 12GB of RAM.
If you perform changes make sure you apply them by running `hal deploy apply` from the **halyard** pod.